# Oozie workflows with sqoop

Tags: hadoop, jobs, sqoop, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I have setup oozie 4.0.0 in my system with Hadoop 1.2.1

My goal is to write sqoop jobs in oozie.As i googled and got following links :-

http://rvs.github.io/oozie/installing.html

http://srikanthayalasomayajulu.blogspot.sg/2013/02/apache-oozie-331-installation-on-apache.html

www.tanzirmusabbir.com/2013/05/chunk-data-import-incremental-import-in.html

All links are really good.

The issue I'm facing is when i run my job.It gives below Exception :-

**JA009: java.io.IOException: Unknown protocol for task tracker: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobSubmissionProtocol at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.getProtocolVersion(TaskTracker.java:763) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622) at org.apache.hadoop**

I'm able to access

**TaskTracker at : localhost:50060  -> it shows 'localhost/127.0.0.1:45162'**

**NameNode    at : localhost:50030  -> it shows Name Node 'localhost:54310'**

In my job.properties i have given 45162 and 54310 ports for tasktracker and namenode respectively.

I can't find this Exception on google except in the apache library code itself.

please help me , I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue .

the jobtracker port mentioned in job.properties should be exactly same to what mentioned in mapred-site.xml

thanks